# How to add select multiple images attribute in category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I want to display more then one images of category in category page so i want to add more then one images in category in backend, please help me

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For add more then one images of category in category page then need to add category images attribute and get them into the category page.

Comment: In Category Image Attribute we can select single image